# Every sunday I have to reboot mac in order to re-establish Ethernet/Lan connection

Tags: macbook-pro, network, mojave, ethernet

I have a MacBook Pro 2018 running Mojave.

At the end of the week - Sunday - or I can wait until Monday - but I have to reboot in order to re-establish Ethernet/LAN connection.

I did some searches - but most talk about WIFI issues.

Any ideal of what the heck is going on here?

I keep the macOS software updated, with regards to Mojave.

Comment: Is it only this one MBP that's impacted?  Any other networked device need to be rebooted, too?  What is the ethernet going to in order to make network connection?

Comment: Curious if you restart Friday night it still breaks Sunday/Monday time frame...

Comment: Is this at home, at work, or somewhere else?   Is it only on Sunday night?  What if you reboot on Friday?

Comment: Also, what update are you on and what searches did you do and what were the results?

Comment: The MBP in question is a work computer - My other MBP 2012 is personal and does not have this issue

I have shutdown the computer on Friday - restart on Saturday - and then on Sunday - the LAN/Network card goes out and it stays that way - even when monday rolls around - which then causes me to restart the machine, re-arrange everything etc.

Searches yielded nothing - most where issues with WIFI.  macOS Mojava V 10.14.6